# Generics in Implicit Class

Tags: scala

I have a have an implicit class like this

```
  private[this] implicit class OptionListUtil[A, B <: List[A]](option: Option[B]) {

      def defaultMap[C](f: A => C): Seq[C] = option.getOrElse(Seq.empty[A]).map(f)
```

But when I go ahead and call it on a Option[List[A]], I get the value defaultMap is not a member of Option[List[A]]

Intellij is not giving any hints so I'm pretty lost

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, if a type parameter only appears once it's suspicious. In this case `B` is actually useless and you can simplify `OptionListUtil` to

```
private[this] implicit class OptionListUtil[A](option: Option[List[A]]) {
  def defaultMap[C](f: A => C): Seq[C] = option.getOrElse(Seq.empty[A]).map(f)
}
```

because `Option` is covariant. This is much simpler for type inference to handle.

Comment: Can you clarify on that last statement? Does this only work because Option is covariant(with traverables I assume)?

Comment: If it weren't, `Option[B]` wouldn't be `Option[List[A]]`. You could still write it as `Option[_ <: List[A]]`.

Answer (score 0):

Go with this instead:

```scala
implicit class OptionListUtil[A,B](option: Option[B])(implicit ev: B <:< List[A]) {

  def defaultMap[C](f: A => C): Seq[C] = option.toSeq.flatMap(_.map(f))
}
```

The current scala compiler can't infer the type `A` in your `B <: List[A]` quite right yet. Asking for the implicit evidence of `<:<` in these cases helps the compiler with type inference.I read somewher that the new dotty compiler apparently doesn't have this issue.

Comment: What's the difference between <: and <:<?

Comment: @fuzzycuffs They both ask for the same thing. ```<:``` is your default way for asking for upper bounds in scala. ```<:<``` asks for the same thing but as an implicit argument.

Comment: `<:` is part of Scala syntax and `<:<` is a [class](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/Predef.scala#L467-L483).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like another way to address this is with higher kinded generics with the class signature like:

```
private[this] implicit class OptionListUtil[A, B[A] <: List[A]](option: Option[B[A]])
```